# How to add onClick in WP Menu using Advanced Custom Filed plugin?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onclick, advanced-custom-fields

I need to add JS attribute - onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'buy');") - to the ONE link in WP menu. I tried with ACF plugin, playing with different types of fields. But it doesn't add this attribute.

I'll ppreciate any ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the back-end, go to the menu settings under Appearance -> Menu's

Click the dropdown for 'Screen options' at the top of the page, ensure 'CSS Classes' is ticked.

Add a class to the link you are attempting to target, for this example I have used 'javascript' as my class.

[image: Link with class]

Now you will need to load a javascript file into the site via the theme as normal, if you're unsure how to do this, open a new question.

Your javascript file should contain the following;

`$(".javascript").click(function () {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'buy');
});`